# Nodejs Not able to create directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I want to post an image to server.But before that I want to make sure that directory is create, before placing an image to a correct folder.The folder that I want to create is `year/month/day/[image]`. I am able to generate the folder  on my local PC, but when I want to apply on the server, an error message is displayed and the folder is not created.I don't know what mistake that I have made, I hope someone can help me solve this problem. 
Thank you in advance.

**PWD**

[image]

**ERROR**

> return binding.mkdir(pathModule._makeLong(path),  Error: ENOENT: no
>   such file or directory, mkdir
>   '/home/eis/development/eis-api-dev/picture/2020/06/01/'

**CODE**

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
     destination: function (req, file, cb) {
         ///output: home/eis/development/eis-api-dev/picture/2020/06/01/
          const dir = path.join(__dirname,_const.IMAGE_FILE_PATH+_const.generateImagePath(null,null,null));
          console.log("path:"+dir);
          fs.exists(dir,exists =>{
               if(!exists){
                    //mkdirp.sync(dir);
                    return fs.mkdirSync(dir,{recursive: true},error => cb(error,dir));

               }
               return cb(null,dir)
          });

     },
     filename: function (req, file, cb) {
       cb(null, file.originalname)
     }
   })
```

Comment: Do you have `picture/2020` This folder created first ? because you cannot create nested folders if the parent folder doesn't exist.

Comment: yes i have folder picture  and 2020 folder,but still got same error.

Answer (score 0):

try to create using mkdirp

```
 if (!fs.existsSync(directoryPath)){
            mkdirp(directoryPath, function (err) {
              if (err) {
                console.log("Error Creating Directory "+directoryPath);
              }
              else {
                    console.log("Creating Directory "+directoryPath);
              }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just have to upgraded latest nodejs version and its worked.

Answer (score 0):

### **To create a directory asynchronously**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = 'newfolder/xyz/';
    fs.exists(path, exists => {
        if (exists) {
            console.log('The directory exists...!!');
        }
        else {
            fs.mkdir(path, { recursive: true }, (error) => {
                console.log(error);
                if (error)
                    // print or display your error
                else {
                    return path;
                }
            });
        }
    });
```